# How to use Phonegap fileTransfer to save file from URL?

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-transfer

I am using Phonegap's fileTransfer api to grab a file from a URL and save it to the local filesystem. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
fileTransfer.download(
    canvasRenderURL,
    "/user/full/",
    function(entry) {
        console.log("Download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("Download error source: " + error.source);
        console.log("Download error target: " + error.target);
        console.log("Error code: " + error.code);
    }
);
```

When I do this I get nothing in the console - success nor error. My inclination is that it is a path problem. What can I do to improve this?

Comment: try `file:///mnt/sdcard/user/full/` or `file:///sdcard/user/full/` in he fileurl, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the console plugin (`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console`) to use `console.log`.

If the problem is that the callbacks never get called, there are open issues concerning this on the apache issue tracker:

- [success callback for file transfer download does not get called every on iOS](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6905)
- [download success callback not called in 0.4.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6525)